# Ubuntu 18.04 app in Windows 10 screen is just showing a blank screen with a blinking cursor

Tags: 18.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Ubuntu 18.04 app in Windows 10 screen is just showing a blank screen with a blinking cursor.

[image: WSL]

I asked [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1174165/error-connection-failed-in-ubuntu-18-04-app-windows-10) question a few minutes ago, then closed the app. Upon starting it again, I'm just getting a blank screen in Ubuntu 18.04 in WSL.

The app works perfectly every time I do a restart of the laptop. Exit it once, and opening on the second time results in a blank screen again.

Comment: @Mathew Well it occurs for me too. But after couple of seconds I get prompt. Try hitting Enter (sounds silly) or enter bash in poweshell.

Comment: It's kind of hit and miss. Restart always works tho.

Comment: restart the pc might be the app isin't getting resources.